# Changing code based on the apply function to the lapply function

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to formulate the code below using the `lapply` function (or actually the `mclapply` function) instead of the `apply` function. I want it to return a matrix or similar and not a list. The `hi` function is very complicated in my actual code, so I just presented a very basic example.

```
hi <- function(a, matrix) {
  hi <- a[1] / a[2] * t(matrix) %*% matrix
  return(hi)
}

a_1 <- t(matrix(1:4))
a_2 <- t(matrix(5:8))
choleski <- matrix(1:4)

result <- apply(rbind(a_1, a_2), 2, hi, matrix=choleski)
```

So my question is basically, how do I reformulate the code above using `lapply` instead of `apply`, i.e. apply the `lapply` function to the `hi` function instead of using the `apply` procedure. An efficient solution would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: `lapply` returns lists. Maybe you want to use `sapply` or an mc* equivalent? Are you asking how to efficiently apply `hi` to each column of `rbind(a_1, a_2)`?

Comment: I'm asking, how I can reformulate the problem such that mclapply/lapply is used instead of the apply procedure, i.e. turn the two matrices into a list apply the lapply function and then turn it into a matrix again.If there is a similar mc function for apply/sapply, it would be great as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you aim to apply `hi` to each column of `rbind(a_1, a_2)`, then you could do something like this:

```
A <- rbind(a_1, a_2)
sapply(seq_len(ncol(A)), function(i) hi(A[, i], choleski))
```

or, more simply (if it's ok to make `rbind(a_1, a_2)` a data.frame):

```
A <- as.data.frame(rbind(a_1, a_2))
sapply(A, function(x) hi(x, choleski))
```

The latter works since a data.frame is a type of list (where columns are its elements), and `sapply` applies function to list elements. By default, `sapply` simplifies its output if possible.